# How to make table background condition with text inside?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Like from my previous question, I want the table cell to contain the symbol of the chart, and the table background to differ based on price>adj_bolliner as green and Price<adj_bollinger as red. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [docs](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_table%7Bdot%7Dcell)

```
table.cell(table_id, column, row, text, width, height, text_color, text_halign, text_valign, text_size, bgcolor, tooltip, text_font_family)
```

The only "twist" you may have in this is that you define a conditional table cell background or table background in the form of a ternary operator.
`bgcolor = myCondition ? color.green : color.red`
You can get your asset name by `syminfo.ticker`